# unique values in categorical variables R estudio

Tags: ggplot2, frame, categorical-data, unique-values

How can I find how many unique values each categorical takes in a data frame and then represent it with a graph? all this in R studio

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. Questions are often answered more easily with some example data and code of attempts to achieve your goal. Together, these should form a minimal reproducible example that people can ideally copy paste into their R sessions. Formulating questions this way often helps you spot mistakes too.

Answer (score 0):

We'll use the tidyverse here.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

You can apply the unique() function to a dataframe to remove any repeat rows.

```
df <- iris %>% unique()
```

The group_by(), summarise() and n() functions let you count the number of instances of a variable in a dataframe.

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(n = n())

## alternatively use count() which does the same thing
df2 <- df %>% count(Species)
```

Finally we can use the ggplot package to create a graph.

```
ggplot() + geom_col(data = df2, aes(x = Species, y = n))
```

If you're not interested in having a separate dataframe with the data in it and want to jump straight to the graph, you can ignore the step with group_by() and summarise() and just use geom_bar().

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(data = df, aes(Species))
```

Comment: also if i would like to do this method with multiple variables, should I do summarise_at for do it for all?